# Alternative to bool TryGetX(out example) with async calls

Tags: c#, .net-5

I really like the `bool TryGetX(out example)` way. The problem is that I want to use `GetKlinesAsync` and it doesn't let me have out/ref in an asynchronous method. Can you recommend to me a way to use it with the async GetKlinesAsync?

I was thinking about:

`public (bool Success, IList<IOhlv> Candles) GetCandlesAsync(...)`

Opinions?

#### Snippet

```cs
public class Client
{
    // Works fine
    public bool TryGetCandles(
        string symbol,
        KlineInterval timeInterval,
        out IList<IOhlcv> candles,
        DateTime? startTime = null,
        DateTime? endTime = null,
        int? limit = null)
    {
        var result = new BinanceClient().Spot.Market.GetKlines(symbol, timeInterval, startTime, endTime, limit);
        candles = result.Data?.Select(x => x.ToCandle()).ToList();
        return result.Success;
    }
    
    // Compile-time error
    public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<bool> TryGetCandlesAsync(
       string symbol,
       KlineInterval timeInterval,
       out IList<IOhlcv> candles, // error CS1988: Async methods cannot have ref, in or out parameters
       DateTime? startTime = null,
       DateTime? endTime = null,
       int? limit = null)
    {
        var result = await new BinanceClient().Spot.Market.GetKlinesAsync(symbol, timeInterval, startTime, endTime, limit).ConfigureAwait(false);
        candles = result.Data?.Select(x => x.ToCandle()).ToList();
        return result.Success;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the `async` keyword, the compiler generates a class / state-machine to hold all the locals and manage the *async and await pattern*. There is no way for the CLR to safely store the address of the out/ref parameters in the fields of the class (Just like iterator methods, and other generated classes).

There are a few options but a common approach is just to return a `ValueTuple`

```
public async Task<(bool success, IList<IOhlcv> candles)> TryGetCandlesAsync(...)
{
    return (result.Success, candles)
}


...

var (success, candles) = await TryGetCandlesAsync();
if (success)
{
    // do something candles;
}
```

If you really wanted this one line, you could use pattern matching.. Though personally I would just stick with the separate statements because in all but the simplest cases this would turn ugly fast, and has the potential to introduce subtle issues if you deviate from the discards

```
if (await TryGetCandlesAsync() is (bool success, _) result && success)
     Console.WriteLine(result.candles);

// or

if (await TryGetCandlesAsync() is (true, _) result)
     Console.WriteLine(result.candles);
```

Comment: Thanks! I saw dotnet's github. They are using `Task<Tuple<bool, BinanceBalance>>` alike. https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/afd10305a37c0ffb2cfb2c2d8446154c68cfa87a/src/EditorFeatures/DiagnosticsTestUtilities/CodeActions/AbstractCodeActionOrUserDiagnosticTest_TestAddDocument.cs#L44. What about it? Which one is preferred

Comment: @nop `ValueTuple` is a struct and unlike `Tuple` (a class) wont be automatically heap allocated in the Microsoft CLR implementation, it also supports `IEquatable`, and has named arguments. For a simple implementation such as with a bool and result,  I would go with the more modern `ValueTuple`, unless you were to reuse this return value over and over again, or are storing a lot of properties (for which a class would make more sense at the cost of an allocation)